# How do you add pydub (and eventally ffmpeg) and to the python path in Windows?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

I'm relatively new to messing around with audio in Python, so I'm trying to set up for it. I need to add pydub to Python path, and I have no idea  how to do it. Please help.
Also, ffmpeg keeps crashing when I try to run it, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Python installed (if not install it), just do

```
pip install pydub
```

and then follow the instructions [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) to add the module to the path variables.

As for this

> Also, FFmpeg keeps crashing when I try to run it, and I don't know what to do.

Reinstall it again, ideally use the [steps here](http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/)